# lib vlc android won't play raw h264?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, libvlc

I need to develop an android app that uses the vlc media player to pick rtsp stream and play raw h264.  I compiled the lib vlc android following the instructions in [AndroidCompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile) using `Mac OSx`. The project compiled with some warnings(shown below) and I was able to run the vlc app on an `Android` tablet.  vlc app plays rtsp stream of a h264 container fine, but it won't play raw h264 from a live cam. The logcat below shows several `unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException` but I have seen these at the beginning of playing any stream, I suppose is vlc trying to figure out which decoder to use. and as the log cat shows, it determines h264. shortly after playbackservice announces start playing, it announces end of playback services.

The vlc android app found at the google playstore is able to play the same feed just fine, so there is nothing wrong with the feed, and the release version has the codec and capability to play raw h264. Could there be a problem with how the `C/C++` libraries compiled? or does the libvlc(compiled) not play raw h264 by default? I have not modified any source code from the [AndroidCompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/Androidcompile) project. Is there anyone that has compiled libvlc and has been able to play a rtsp stream of raw h264? or should I look into piping the stream into a container and playing from the container, how could i do so?

my machine runs Mac OS X,prior to running compile.sh script I installed the build tools recommended, and the project runs from `Android Studio`.
below the logcat, and a snippet of the warnings when the project compiled.

```
>07-15 14:38:26.139    9037-9037/? D/PlaybackService.Client﹕ Service Connected
>07-15 14:38:26.139    9037-9037/? V/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ Creating on-the-fly Media object for rtsp://root:****@10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720
>07-15 14:38:26.139    9037-9037/? V/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ Loading position 0 in [org.videolan.vlc.MediaWrapper@42001178]
>07-15 14:38:26.149      439-744/? I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@41f316d0org.videolan.vlc.PlaybackService$1@41e62750
>07-15 14:38:26.149      439-727/? I/MediaFocusControl﹕ Remote Control   registerMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{4220baf0: PendingIntentRecord{41fd9ab0 org.videolan.vlc.debug broadcastIntent}}
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [72210838] core generic: creating audio output
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [73a56e28] core audio output: looking for audio output module matching "android_audiotrack,none": 4 candidates
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [73a56e28] core audio output: using audio output module "android_audiotrack"
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [72210838] core generic: keeping audio output
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: Creating an input for 'rtsp://10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720'
>07-15 14:38:26.149    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: `rtsp://root:****@10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `root:****@10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720'
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: specified demux `any'
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='any' location='root:****@10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720' file='(null)'
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] core demux: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 6 candidates
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: version 2015.06.24
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Opening connection to
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ 10.168.1.45
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ , port
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ 554
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ ...
>07-15 14:38:26.159    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.179    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ ...remote connection opened
>    Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 2
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>07-15 14:38:26.179    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received 143
>07-15 14:38:26.179    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ new bytes of response data.
>    Received a complete OPTIONS response:
>    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
>    CSeq: 2
>    Public: DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, >TEARDOWN
>    Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 20:32:31 GMT
>    Sending request:
>07-15 14:38:26.179    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ DESCRIBE rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?>videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 3
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Accept: application/sdp
>07-15 14:38:26.189    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode >stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.189    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received 247 new bytes of >response data.
>    Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
>    RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
>    CSeq: 3
>    WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", stale=FALSE
>    WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E"
>    Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 20:32:31 GMT
>    Resending...
>    Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 4
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720", >response="23cc09ed9e29fc64404cddae9c8b44cc"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Accept: application/sdp
>07-15 14:38:26.199    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.199    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.209    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: RTP >subsession 'video/H264'
>07-15 14:38:26.209    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received 809 new bytes of >response data.
>    Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
>    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
>    CSeq: 4
>    Content-Type: application/sdp
>    Content-Base: rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/
>    Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 20:32:31 GMT
>    Content-Length: 632
>    v=0
>    o=- 1436992351621972 1436992351621972 IN IP4 10.168.1.45
>    s=Media Presentation
>    e=NONE
>    b=AS:50000
>    t=0 0
>    a=control:rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720
>    a=range:npt=0.000000-
>    m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
>    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>    b=AS:50000
>    a=framerate:25.0
>    >a=transform:1.000000,0.000000,0.000000;0.000000,0.900000,0.000000;0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
>    a=control:rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/trackID=1?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720
>    a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
>    a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; profile-level-id=420029; sprop->parameter-sets=Z0IAKeKQCgC3YC3AQEBpB4kRUA==,aM48gA==
    Sending request:
>07-15 14:38:26.209    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ SETUP rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/trackID=1?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 5
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/", response="8c5fc662991d144c3d2d319abdb09802"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=53078-53079
>07-15 14:38:26.219      576-588/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2420K, 79% free 8246K/38240K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
>07-15 14:38:26.229    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.239    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.259    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.259    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.269      439-722/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41c773b8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@4225d8a0
>07-15 14:38:26.289    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received 198 new bytes of response data.
>07-15 14:38:26.289    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received a complete SETUP >response:
>    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
>    CSeq: 5
>    Session: 1EB7CD91; timeout=60
>    Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=53078->53079;server_port=50124-50125;ssrc=57E15CB7;mode="PLAY"
>    Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 20:32:31 GMT
>07-15 14:38:26.289    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: selecting program id=0
>07-15 14:38:26.289    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
>07-15 14:38:26.289    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Sending request: PLAY rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 6
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/", response="20a147ef13ac0dd25e485b077f24d072"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Session: 1EB7CD91
>    Range: npt=0.000-
>07-15 14:38:26.299    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.339    9037-9037/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 732K, 15% free 6659K/7816K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
>07-15 14:38:26.359      439-729/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.PLAY_FROM_VIDEOGRID flg=0x18000000 cmp=org.videolan.vlc.debug/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity (has extras)} from pid 9037
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received 233 new bytes of response data.
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Received a complete PLAY response:
>    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
>    CSeq: 6
>    Session: 1EB7CD91
>    Range: npt=0-
>    RTP-Info: url=rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/trackID=1?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720;seq=31479;rtptime=1375710016
    Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2015 20:32:31 GMT
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: We have a timeout of 60 seconds
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: spawned timeout thread
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] core demux: using access_demux module "live555"
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: video is disabled, not selecting ES 0x0
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73c1aea0] core demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73c1aea0] core demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: `rtsp://root:****@10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720' successfully opened
>07-15 14:38:26.409    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Sending request: TEARDOWN rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/trackID=1?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 7
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/", response="c03b9bbe9546d7c65fdc193c8cee8c8f"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Session: 1EB7CD91
>07-15 14:38:26.439    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.439      116-336/? W/AudioFlinger﹕ write blocked for 374 msecs, 150 delayed writes, thread 0x40c51008
>07-15 14:38:26.469    9037-9037/? I/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ Media.Event.ParsedChanged
>07-15 14:38:26.469    9037-9037/? D/VLC/MediaWrapper﹕ Title rtsp://10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720
>07-15 14:38:26.469    9037-9037/? D/VLC/MediaWrapper﹕ Artist null
>07-15 14:38:26.469    9037-9037/? D/VLC/MediaWrapper﹕ Genre null
>07-15 14:38:26.469    9037-9037/? D/VLC/MediaWrapper﹕ Album null
>07-15 14:38:26.479    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] live555 demux: tk-rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9412/? E/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Sending request:
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ GET_PARAMETER rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 8
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/", response="eef50526f953157a541671aac10b7d99"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Session: 1EB7CD91
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ [ 07-15 14:38:26.489  9037: 9412 D/VLC      ]
    [73890268] live555 demux: RTSP track Close, 0 track remaining
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: EOF reached
>07-15 14:38:26.489    9037-9412/? D/VLC﹕ [73890268] core demux: removing module "live555"
>07-15 14:38:26.499    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ Sending request:
>07-15 14:38:26.499    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ TEARDOWN rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720 RTSP/1.0
>    CSeq: 9
>    Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CE6D77E", nonce="00478005Y607330b149b17a0889d51cdbe1476bcbc90d0", uri="rtsp://10.168.1.45:554/axis-media/media.amp/", response="c03b9bbe9546d7c65fdc193c8cee8c8f"
>    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2015.06.24)
>    Session: 1EB7CD91
>07-15 14:38:26.499    9037-9052/? E/VLC-std﹕ [ 07-15 14:38:26.499  9037: 9412 D/VLC      ]
    [73acc248] core input: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
>07-15 14:38:26.499    9037-9412/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=15: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
>07-15 14:38:26.499    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.519    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.529    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.709      439-729/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1741K, 32% free 10561K/15308K, paused 142ms, total 142ms
>07-15 14:38:26.729    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.749    9037-9037/? I/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ MediaPlayer.Event.Playing
>07-15 14:38:26.759    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.769    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.789    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.799    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:26.829    9037-9037/? D/VLC/VideoPlayerActivity﹕ MediaRouter information : android.media.MediaRouter@41e6f950
>07-15 14:38:26.829    9037-9037/? I/VLC/VideoPlayerActivity﹕ No secondary display detected
>07-15 14:38:26.959    9037-9037/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1372K, 22% free 6328K/8044K, paused 24ms, total 26ms
>07-15 14:38:27.029    9037-9037/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>07-15 14:38:27.309    9037-9037/? I/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ MediaPlayerEndReached
>07-15 14:38:27.339    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:27.349    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:27.359    9037-9037/? E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
>07-15 14:38:27.359    9037-9037/? W/VLC/PlaybackService﹕ Warning: invalid next index, aborted !
>07-15 14:38:27.359    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [73acc248] core input: Destroying the input for 'rtsp://10.168.1.45/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=1280x720'
>07-15 14:38:27.359    9037-9037/? D/VLC﹕ [73a56e28] core audio output: removing module "android_audiotrack"
>07-15 14:38:27.379      439-744/? I/MediaFocusControl﹕ AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@41f316d0org.videolan.vlc.PlaybackService$1@41e62750
>07-15 14:38:27.379     439-1293/? I/MediaFocusControl﹕ Remote Control   unregisterMediaButtonIntent() for PendingIntent{42033a48: PendingIntentRecord{41fd9ab0 org.videolan.vlc.debug broadcastIntent}}
>07-15 14:38:27.399    9037-9037/? D/PlaybackService.Client﹕ Service Connected
>07-15 14:38:27.479    9037-9037/? E/VLC/VideoPlayerActivity﹕ Invalid surface size
>07-15 14:38:27.489    9037-9037/? D/VLC/VideoPlayerActivity﹕ Continuing playback from AudioService at index 0
>07-15 14:38:27.489      439-453/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed org.videolan.vlc.debug/org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity: +1s48ms
>07-15 14:38:27.499    9037-9037/? I/AppCompatDelegate﹕ The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
>07-15 14:38:30.069      116-336/? D/AudioHardware﹕ AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
> ## Quoted Heading ##


Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:iomx.13: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -lstagefright -lmedia -lbinder    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:iomx.14: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc -lstagefright -lmedia -lbinder    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:vlcjni: non-system libraries in linker flags: /Users/breinosa/Library/Android/android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liba52_plugin.a
```

Comment: Have you tried to play rtsp streaming in VLC Android Application??

Comment: I found same issue. Trying to play rtmp but no luck. Compile by virtual linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in a number of places:

```
    Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You need to figure out what is causing the NPE.

Without seeing your code, my initial guess would be that it is passing a `null` to the bitmap factory, and saying "decode that".

Comment: the code can be found at git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git , I didn't make any changes to it.

Comment: So this is really not a programming question?

Comment: Turns out the unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException is generated when vlc attempts to load an album cover for the audio stream, however the stream I'm trying to play doesn't have audio, is video only. therefore these null pointer exceptions are not related to playing h264